# How do i get values(inputs) from the queue and calculate them?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

With the code below, i'm putting the values of the input in the queue. But i can't seem to figure out how i can get them out and calculate the inputs?

Inputs should be like this: 1 + 1 , 5 * 5 , 10 - 8 for example. Which then checks the first and second number are int and if it has an operator in between, if correct putting it in the queue.

```
def producer(queue):
    operators = ('+', '-', '*', '/', '%')

    while True:
        inputs = str(input("Give calculation: ( 1 + 1 , 5 - 2 etc.. type 'end' to end the program ")).split()
        inputs2 = ' '.join(inputs)

        if inputs2 in ['end']:
            print('Bye')
            break

        if inputs[1] not in operators:
            print('Wrong operator input:\n')
            continue

        try:
            int(inputs[0]) and int(inputs[2])
        except ValueError:
            print('Wrong number input: \n')

        else:
            queue.put(inputs2)
            break




def consumer():
    while True:
        q2 = queue.get()
        print (q2)

       #if q2[1] in ['+']:
           #print(int(q2[0]) + int(q2[2]))

queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
t = threading.Thread(target = producer, args=(queue,))
t.start()
t2 = threading.Thread(target = consumer)
t2.start()
```

Comment: Don't you have an indentation issue at the while statement?

Comment: While True: on the producer method seems to have wrong indentation. could you check if that is intentional.

Comment: fixed that. Didn't copy it very well in here.

Comment: Do you want to be passing the `queue` as a parameter to the `consumer` process, like you're doing for the `producer`?

Comment: I want the producer to be reading the input and putting it into the queue and the consumer should get it from the queue, calculate the input(1 + 1 for example) and print the answer onscreen ( 1 + 1 = 2)